# CSS: Vertically Align Text next to Icon using Floating Divs

Tags: css, image, css-float, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align a Text next to an Icon/Image, I want the text or the image to be align vertically but the vertical-align is not being applied, it might have something to do with the floats

Here's an image explainng what I want to do:
[image]

Here's what I have so far:

---- HTML ---

```
<ul class="toolboxItems">
    <li>
        <div class="image">
             <img src="someImage.png">
        </div>

        <div class="label">
           <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</label>
        </div>
    <li>

    <li>
        /* more of the same .... */
    </li>
<ul>
```

---- CSS ----

```
ul.toolboxItems li {margin-bottom:10px;}
.image {float:left; width:30px;}
.label {float:left; width:150px; vertical-align:middle;}
```

I tried using display:table / table-cell but it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the CSS table display properties which are [supported in everything](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) (besides IE 7 or below).

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hgssm/1/

```
.toolboxItems {
  display: table;
}

.toolboxItems li {
  display: table-row;
}

.toolboxItems .image,
.toolboxItems .label {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.toolboxItems .label {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much jesse, exactly what I wanted. I never thought this could be done without floats.